# Copy files isn't finished when Activity starts, how to fix it?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a large SQLiteDatabase that I copy from Assets to SDCard before opening that database. But I seem to be missing something because the Activity that uses that database can query the database before the copy is done, which causes a SQLiteException.

In my constructor I do this:

```
private DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    mContext = context;
    DB_FILE_PATH = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
    try {

        createDataBase();
        openDataBase();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The createDatabase method is doing:

```
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

        dbExist = checkDataBase();

        if (dbExist) {

        } else {
            this.getReadableDatabase();

            try {
                copyDataBase();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                throw new Error("Error copying database");
            }
        }
    }
```

I think you understand. However, my issue and question is how I can check if the database is completed copy before opening the database? Clearly I'm not doing it correctly now.

Regards,
Jonas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If some operation is very long, you should do that in asn async task and manage all other operation through temporary variable. [Async task](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

my sugegstion is to copy the db from assets in an async task and warn the user (toast or popup) or block the user interation (ex. with a progress dialog) until the Copy is completed.

private boolean isCopyingDb = true inside onCreate()

```
 private class Copy Db extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(Void... ) {
      isCopyingDb = true;
        //copy db
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         isCopyingDb = false;
         pdia.dismiss();
     }
            @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pdia = new ProgressDialog(this);
            pdia.setMessage("Doing background..");
            pdia.show();
        }
 }
```

in your activity check the status of isCopyingDb. If false, use the db.

**edit:**
block the user with a simple progressDialog.. or implement a progressbar, so the user know how much time he should wait.

Comment: This is a good solution, at least in theory, the only problem is that I do that (using an async task) and that's the reason why I have the problem, eg the copy thread isn't locking up the gui and therefore can a user of the app query the database even though the copy operation isn't finished. That's why I won't mark the question as solved just yet.
However, I might have got an idea from this and I will try it and then I might tag this as answered.

Comment: you could block the ui with a progressbar. I edit the answer.

Comment: Oki, that's okay! Thanks for the idea! Regards, Jonas